# Can you fetch schemas from spark databases via jdbc?

Tags: database, scala, pyspark, schema, databricks

I'm trying to connect from an instance A in databricks to another databricks instance B to read its tables and schemas (databases)

How can I fetch the schemas from instance B using jdbc?

This is what I've tried:

```
sparkUrl = f"jdbc:{UrlPrefix}://{Host}:{Port}/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath={Db};AuthMech=3;UID={Uid};PWD={Pwd};UseNativeQuery=1"
spark.read.jdbc( url=sparkUrl, table=f'(SHOW SCHEMAS)')
```

But the system always return an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][SparkJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: SHOW; line 1 pos 15
```

**If I run a "normal" SELECT statement from instance A against instance B tables it returns the records without errors.**

I read in the documentation that the jdbc driver always tries to surround the sql statement like

```
select * from (query)
```

It seems that this is the behavior that is happening, hence that's how I get the error.

Can I stop the default behavior of the jdbc driver to wrap jdbc queries so I can run the straight code in instance B?

I can switch to scala if such option is available.

Comment: why not just use JDBC directly instead of `spark.read.jdbc`?

Comment: Hi Alex. Do you mean using jaydebeapi or Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, the `show` keyword was not recognizable so used alternative methods to get the same. I am using the `databricks-sql-connector` provided by databricks to query another instance. I am providing a detailed link for reference - https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/python-sql-connector.html

1. You need to install the connector on the instance
2. generate access_token to access the cluster
3. you can get all the hostname and path details on the cluster jdbc/odbc tab.

```
from databricks import sql
with sql.connect(server_hostname="databricks.com",
                 http_path="sql/protocolv1/o/0/2",
                 access_token="asdjaskdjaskXXXX") as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SHOW SCHEMAS ")
        result = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in result:
          print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you yogesh. I will try and post my results later.

Comment: worked like a charm, note to self package name should be `databricks-sql-connector`