# How to get schema without loading table data in Databricks?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, schema, databricks

I am working on Databricks and I use spark to laod and publish data to a SQL database. One of the task I need to do is to get the schema of a table of my database and therefore see the datatypes of each column. The only way I am able to do it so far is by loading the whole table and then extracting the schema.

```
df_tableA = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
        .option("url", datasource_url) \
        .option("dbtable", table_name) \
        .option("user", dbuser) \
        .option("password", dbpassword) \
        .option("driver", driver) \
        .load()
```

However my goal is to get just the schema without loading the entire table since I want to speed up the process and I do not want to overload the memory.

Would you be able to suggest a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Comment: See [Can you fetch schemas from spark databases via jdbc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71564482/can-you-fetch-schemas-from-spark-databases-via-jdbc)

Comment: `.load()` does not load entire table. It's just metadata actually. It will only pull the data when you run an action like `saveAsTable` or `collect`. So imho it should be fine (and fast) to just use `(...).load().schema`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, `load` does not load the table into memory. But if you want, you can use a dummy query and pass to `dbtable` like `.option("dbtable", "(select * from table where 1 = 2) t")`